# MediaScannerConnection produces android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked

Tags: android, sample

I'm using the MediaScannerConnection example code from the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ExternalStorage.html)

The snippet I'm using is:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
    context,
    new String[] { permFile.getAbsolutePath() }, 
    null,
    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

            android.util.Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            android.util.Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
});
```

When I run this code, I get an FC dialog with the following from the [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file):

```
4-20 23:17:45.988: ERROR/ActivityThread(3015): Activity com.my.package.name has leaked ServiceConnection android.media.MediaScannerConnection@40715c70 that was originally bound here
04-20 23:17:45.988: ERROR/ActivityThread(3015): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.my.package.name has leaked ServiceConnection android.media.MediaScannerConnection@40715c70 that was originally bound here
```

What am I doing wrong?

FYI, I'm running this from a background thread using AsyncTask.

Comment: I have the feeling that MediaScannerConnection is leaking the listener. Somehow it doesn't get cleaned up and there isn't a method to reset the listener. I am facing the same kind of issue at this moment. Did you solve this in the mean time?

Comment: I don't remember. I posted this a year ago. I'll have to go back and check.

Comment: I'm still seeing this on KitKat. Pretty sure this is an Android issue, not a usage issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I noticed the same kind of error message using the code snippet provided with the documentation of [Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29).

The code works fine as expected and makes a **new file visible in the device gallery**, but at the same time prints the error about the `leaked ServiceConnection`.

Looking at the internal Android code of the `MediaScannerConnection` it seems some kind of mechanism exists to stop the service after the last file. Maybe it doesn't work when given only one file?

I ended up using an entirely different solution by informing the MediaScanner via Intent. This works fine too and it is not producing any warnings:

```
Intent mediaScannerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri fileContentUri = Uri.fromFile(permFile); // With 'permFile' being the File object
mediaScannerIntent.setData(fileContentUri);
this.sendBroadcast(mediaScannerIntent); // With 'this' being the context, e.g. the activity
```

It seems this is the preferred way, and it is mentioned in the [Android Training about Taking Photos](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery) too.

Answer (score 12):

Use `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Comment: Nice answer. When using `IntentService` this eliminates the leakage.

Comment: Works great in non-intent Service too!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the voice recognizer when I would change layouts, etc.

All I had to do was add a unregisterReceiver, kind of like this in the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```