# MediaScanner ServiceConnectionLeaked

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I use this class to scan my app image in SDCard.

```
public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
private File mFile;

public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
    mFile = f;
    mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
    mMs.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
}

@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    mMs.disconnect();
}
}
```

It worked but in my LogCat it always shown an error:

```
12-29 16:44:16.022: ERROR/ActivityThread(21807): Activity com.cny.ecard.CustomListDialog has leaked ServiceConnection android.media.MediaScannerConnection@450fb8e0 that was originally bound here
12-29 16:44:16.022: ERROR/ActivityThread(21807): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.cny.ecard.CustomListDialog has leaked ServiceConnection android.media.MediaScannerConnection@450fb8e0 that was originally bound here
12-29 16:44:16.022: ERROR/ActivityThread(21807):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:1121)
12-29 16:44:16.022: ERROR/ActivityThread(21807):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:1016)
12-29 16:44:16.022: ERROR/ActivityThread(21807):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:863)
12-29 16:44:16.022: ERROR/ActivityThread(21807):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
12-29 16:44:16.022: ERROR/ActivityThread(21807):     at android.media.MediaScannerConnection.connect(MediaScannerConnection.java:117)
12-29 16:44:16.022: ERROR/ActivityThread(21807):     at com.cny.ecard.SingleMediaScanner.<init>(SingleMediaScanner.java:19)
```

What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MediaScannerConnection produces android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739140/mediascannerconnection-produces-android-app-serviceconnectionleaked)

Comment: @user430926 i m getting this error when using correct answer 12-29 11:08:10.331: E/AndroidRuntime(29810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.mygallery/com.mygallery.ImageShownActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=29810, uid=10385

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For scanning a single file, or scanning a file from a context in which you can't bind to a service (e.g., from a `BroadcastReceiver`), user430926's comment deserves to be a separate answer:

```
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE); 
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Comment: One-liner: `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));`

Comment: @acj i m getting this error  when using this code 12-29 11:08:10.331: E/AndroidRuntime(29810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.mygallery/com.mygallery.ImageShownActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=29810, uid=10385

Comment: @ErumHannan The permissions have been tightened in recent versions of Android. You may need to use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` instead.

Comment: This method is no more applicable because starting from Nougat, file cannot be exposed in a public intent and you receive a security exception

Comment: @greywolf82 is there any documentation for that breaking change in Nougat?

Answer (score 2):

the android media scanner service like bind service, so when you finish the scan, 
you can use `context.unbindService` to unbind.

Comment: public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
     mMs.disconnect();
     c.unbindService(mMs);
 }

I have add  c.unbindService(mMs); onScanCompleted but it still have that error. Any other suggestion?

Comment: SingleMediaScanner this class has be created twice or more?

Comment: Yes, if i have to scan more than 1 file.

I have try to use other code.


onCreate:
scanner = new MediaScannerConnection(CustomListDialog.this, null);  

Every time i scan image:
scanner.connect();        
scanner.scanFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), "image/png");        
scanner.disconnect();

But it still give me that error msg. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [LoadedApk](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/LoadedApk.java&ct=rc&cd=2&exact_package=android&q=leaked%20ServiceConnection&l=520) 

in the android source code, it some like the CustomListDialog will be destroyed, check the bind service, found the service has not be unbind.

so, suggestion override `finish` method to `scanner.disconnect` to unbind service.

Comment: I found another solution:
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);